# Using a single policy method to cover every action on a resource

Tags: laravel, authorization

I have a resource named `Post`. Every `Post` is related to a single `User`, and a `User` may have several (or zero) `Posts`.

I'm using `Route::resource` to map routes for every possible action on the `Post` resource to a single resource controller, `PostController`.

Now, I wish to implement a policy for the `Post` resource. Aiming to keep everything as simple and fool-proof as possible, I'd like to make the policy as follows:

- Every user is authorized to make any action that doesn't require an existing `Post` (e.g. create).
- A `User` is only authorized to access its own `Posts` for every action that accesses a `Post` (e.g. edit, update, delete).

What I'm trying to do right now is to create a single policy method called `access`, which would check that the `Post` is owned by the `User`. Then, in my `PostController`, every method that has a `Post` object in its parameters (such as `edit(Post $post)`) would begin with

`$this->authorize('access', $post);`

However, I don't like that I need to put those lines manually. If I ever forget one of those, I'll have a security hole right there.

On the other hand, I have the `authorizeResource` method, which makes authorization automatic but requires the policy to have several methods so they are mapped to the each of the controller's methods. Also, I tried to use the [`Authorize`/`can` middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-middleware), but it didn't work (maybe because I used it on a `Route::resource` mapping).

The question is: What would be the cleanest and more secure way to achieve the result I described (i.e. authorizing every possible action that accesses a resource with the exact same rule)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `authorizeResource()` and override the `resourceAbilityMap()` method in your controller. The latter method returns a mapping from controller methods to the policy methods that will be called.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L105

E.g.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the map of resource methods to ability names.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function resourceAbilityMap()
    {
        return [
            'edit' => 'access',
            'update' => 'access',
            'destroy' => 'access',
        ];
    }

    // ...
}
```