# Laravel - Policy authorization on user and object that both belong to something

Tags: laravel, authorization, policy, laravel-passport

I want to authorize my API of my Laravel application.
My structure right now is like this:

Users belong to an organization, and the organization has many (lets say) objects.
Now I want that only users can view/edit/create/delete objects, that belong to the organization they are part of.

My API route for viewing the objects is:

```
Route::get('organizations/{id}/objects','ObjectController@indexOrganization')->middleware('auth:api');
```

I created the Models User, Organization and Object. They all have their own Controller.

I created the ObjectPolicy and tried this:

```
public function view(User $user, Object $object)
    {
      return $user->organization_id === $object->organization_id;
    }
```

And then I added `->middleware('can:view,object');` to the route. 
Unfortunately, it does not work and the Laravel documentation does not provide the information I need.

Can someone help?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!! I Changed everything but I still get a 403 response.

Here is my code:

Route:

```
Route::get('organizations/{organization}/objects','ObjectController@index Organization')->middleware('auth:api', 'can:view, organization');
```

OrganizationPolicy:

```
public function view(User $user, Organization $organization)
{
    return $user->organization_id === $organization->id;
}
```

ObjectController:

```
public function indexOrganization(Organization $organization)
{
  $objects = $organization->objects;
  return ObjectResource::collection($objects);
}
```

I also added this to my `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    App\Organization::class => App\Policies\OrganizationPolicy::class,
];
```

**EDIT 2 / SOLUTION**

The answer from newUserName02 works! The problem was inside the `AuthServiceProvider`. After I changed the code (see above in Edit) there to:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Organization' => 'App\Policies\OrganizationPolicy',
];
```

it worked!

Comment: Is the `{id}` in the route for the organization or the object? Can you post the controller code for `ObjectController@indexOrganization`?

Comment: The id is for the Organisation.. I Want to fetch all objects of it... I Post the code later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy method should to match the arguments you are passing to the controller. It looks like you are passing the id of the `Organization` in the route, but you are trying to check the `Object` on the policy.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-middleware

You can take advantage of Laravel's implicit model binding to inject the Organization into the controller like this:

Route:

```
Route::get('organizations/{organization}/objects','ObjectController@indexOrganization')->middleware('auth:api', 'can:view,organization');
```

Policy:

```
public function view(User $user, Organization $organization)
{
  return $user->organization_id === $organization->id;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function indexOrganization(Organization $organization)
{
    ...
}
```

Notice that `{organization}` in the route matches `organization` in the `->middleware()` call, which matches `$organization` in the policy and controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer- I will try it asap and mark it as correct if it works :-) !!

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong!! Still 403. See my edit :-(

Comment: I found my problem !! Had to change `App\Organization::class => App\Policies\OrganizationPolicy::class,` to `'App\Organization' => 'App\Policies\OrganizationPolicy'`  --- One more question: Is it possible to "map" a full resource instead of ::get , ::post , ... ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `authorizeResource()` and override the `resourceAbilityMap()` method in your controller. See my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765749/using-a-single-policy-method-to-cover-every-action-on-a-resource/52770315#52770315

Comment: How would that be in my example. Lets say I want to show a single object with the Route: `...api/objects/1`. So it executes the `show($id)` function `ObjectController`. How can I map it to the `OrganizationPolicy` so only persons who belong to the organization can view a single object of the organization? You are helping me so much! Thanks!!

Comment: If there are different models that you need to check in the controller, you can't use `authorizeResource()` to cover everything out-of-the-box. You will have to create a separate `ObjectPolicy` to handle objects. Then, if you split up the routes between controllers depending on which model gets passed in the route, you can make a single `authorizeResource()` call in each controller. Or, if you want it all in one controller, you can use `authorizeResource()` to handle one model/policy and call `$this->authorize(...)` inside the controller methods that use the other policy.